# cakePHP input with characters counting

Tags: html, cakephp

I have the HTML code like this:

```
<label>Main Text (<span class="main_text_count">0</span><span>) Characters</span></label>
<textarea name="data[News][sentence]" id="main_text" class="form-control"  required rows="8"></textarea>
```

And I don't know how to create a text area like this, using Form helper of cakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

Simply done using the Form Helper (both for [CakePHP 2](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::textarea) and [CakePHP 3](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-textareas)):-

```
echo $this->Form->textarea(
    'News.sentence', 
    [
        'id' => 'main_text',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'rows' => 8,
        'label' => 'Main Text (<span class="main_text_count">0</span><span>) Characters</span>'
    ]
);
```

In future make sure you've fully read Cake's documentation.

Comment: This might need escape=>false. Not sure though.